# Equations for Polygons in the Plane

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]I've notice that one can describe a subset of polygons in the plane with equations of the form
$$\sum_{i}|x-x_i|+|y-y_i| = c>0.$$
Consider for example this highly-symmetrical $16$-sided polygon
$$|x|+|y|+|x-1|+|y-1|+|x-2|+|y-2|+|x-3|+|y-3| = 15.$$
One interesting aspect is that the number of sides changes with $c$.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that $16$ sides is the maximum we can achieve with $i=\{0,1,2,3\}$.
My questions are firstly, if there a name for this type of equation (perhaps a generalization of an ellipse in the taxi-cab geometry?).  Secondly, is there a way to calculate, given an equation of the form above, the number of sides of the polygon?